# What is the point of using "signonce" flag in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, signtool

If we defined the `SignTool`, there are two flags in the `[Files]` section we can use: `sign` and `signonce`?

I can't really think of any case, why should I ever use `signonce` flag? When I recompile the script with the `sign` flag, nothing bad happens and the files stay signed. When do we really need to use that flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you pack whole directory tree. Some of the files may be signed already and some not. And you may want to keep the original signature for the already signed files, and sign only those that are not signed yet.

Comment: But it's no big deal if I sign the same files with the same certificate except the fact that it takes time for the installer to process the signing operation. That's also why I might need the `signonce` flag - to save time.

Comment: I'm not sure if the signature is replaced or if they accumulate.

Comment: @JConstantine Previously the signing used to always show a popup console window. So it got annoying to have it keep showing when not needed. Eventually they added the option to sign the file minimized which made it better. Please also keep in mind that the signing accesses a time server and for some users their internet connection might be slow. So signing unecessarily can impede compile time for them.